# Publishing error "can't find file..." when the file exists in the path specified

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to publish out to Azure and I'm suddenly receiving an error

> Copying file bin\de\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll to obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\de\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll failed. Could not find file 'bin\de\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll'.

The file is definitely in the path.  I've deleted everything from bin and obj to force a complete rebuild but nothings seems to work.  Ideas?

Comment: when you choose publish configuration, is the option "Precompile during publish" checked?  This option used to give me tons of problems.

Comment: That setting is off.  We've published the app for months and never had a problem and suddenly we're getting this error.

Comment: Have you checked if you compiled in Release also? It could be that the project has been compiled in Debug. Assuming that is correct, not sure what else could be happening here. Maybe check in your CSPROJ (by text-editing it) if that dll is referenced there by text and if it has sth strange

Comment: Oddly, a build or rebuild produces no errors.  It's only when we try and publish out to Azure that we see this error.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact error but unable to figure out why. Cleaning and rebuild doesn't help anything too.

Following this 
[link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1971782.aspx?Publish+failure+due+to+inability+to+find+files+in+the+bin+folder), I exclude both bin and obj in my solution, tried to publish again and it work like a charm.

Hope this helps